# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Rails 6 webapp search bar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, webpacker

Whenever I try to use the search bar in my webapp I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' in my console. No results are filtered on the page either. I followed this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBB3PMmr4is&list=PL3mtAHT_eRez6d-PavT6O1KtcMe7mOr-C&index=8&t=0s

My index.html.erb file looks like this

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <%= form_tag(search_path, method: "get", remote: true) do %>
        <div class="input-group mb5">
          <div class="col-8" style = "padding:0">
            <%= text_field_tag :search, '', class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search...', onkeydown: 'clickSubmit()' %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4" style = "padding:0">
            <%= select_tag "filter", options_for_select(
              [
                'Select filter', 
                'Dairy free', 
                'Gluten Free', 
                'Peanut Free', 
                'Vegan', 
                'Vegetarian'
              ]), class: 'custom-select', onchange: 'clickSubmit()' %>
          </div>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-dark', id: 'search_submit', style: "display:none" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu-products-container">
    <%= render 'menu/products'%>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function clickSubmit() {
    $("#search_submit").click();
  }
</script>
```

and here is my environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append( Provide,
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
module.exports = environment
```

I've ran `yarn add jquery` but the problem persists

Comment: As far as I know, adding the variables to the webpack config only makes it available in every module. To have it on window, you'd need to add it to window: `window.$ = $`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Provide was not in quotation marks in environment.js.
Using 'Provide' instead solved the issue.